# How to set a condition for .htaccess directives

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, error-logging

I have configured `.htaccess` file to append `PHP` errors into a log file by:

```
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/user_id/public_html/PHP_errors.php
php_value error_reporting 6143
```

and It works fine in the remote server(linux). But the above path does not exist in the local server(windows). I tried:

```
php_value error_log  ./PHP_errors.php
```

And it works in local, But it does not work in the remote server.

Is it possible to restrict the above directions to the remote server? Something like:

```
Condition %{http_host} ^example.com$
php_value error_log  /home/user_id/public_html/PHP_errors.php

Condition %{http_host} ^localhost$
php_value error_log  ./PHP_errors.php
```

(I have not access to php.ini file in the remote server but of course I can change it in the local)

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: @anubhava apache version is: 2.4.17

Answer (score 4):

Using Apache 2.4 you can use this conditional snippet:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ m#^(www\.)?example\.com$#">
   php_value error_log  /home/user_id/public_html/PHP_errors.php
</If>

<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ m#localhost#">
   php_value error_log ./PHP_errors.php
</If>
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, it works on local(2.4) but unfortunately the version of apache on remote server is (2.2.19) and fails.

Comment: Right as I said this only Apache 2.4 solution. Anyway if you have different installing of apache then you can have a different htaccess as well for older apache

Answer (score 0):

You can control this from PHP. So you can have a configuration file in PHP that is included on the start of application and sets error_log() and error_reporting().

Then you can either have several versions of this file based on your environment (local or remote) or you can check for $_SERVER variable to set up correct paths.

Comment: I'd like to do this in `.htaccess` file. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar question with a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4139899/5550193

Additionally, you may not want to give your log file the extension `.php` as it opens up for some potential exploits. Better call it `.log` or something else that doesn't have potential to be sent to an interpreter by Apache.